Woher kommt "Waka waka" als Ausdruck sich zu beeilen? (Babysprache)
Ich habe schon gesucht, aber entweder schreibe ich es falsch oder seit der WM mit dem Lied von Shakira "It's time for Africa" findet man es nicht mehr...
Bei uns im Sauerland (Meine Mutter kommt allerdings aus Sachsen-Anhalt) haben wir immer Waka Waka Waka (3x wiederholt oder mehr) gesagt, wenn ein Kind sich beeilen soll. Wie schnell anziehen oder schnell zurück zu Mama an die Hand kommen.
Sagt man das auch woanders? Und woher kommt das? Ich glaube nicht, dass es vom Videospiel Pacman kommt, weil es bei uns schon vorher in Gebrauch war.

Keine Ahnung, aber Wacker, Wacker, Wacker ist was Fozzy-Bär aus der Muppetsshow ruft, wenn seine Witze nicht zünden.

@Janka - My first thought was Fozzie Bear as well. (See this entry on the Muppet fandom wiki.) Googling the phrase led me down a rabbit hole of world music, for example here, and here. Can anyone verify that this is actually German? Sometimes families have their own codes and in-jokes not understandable in terms of the language/dialect they speak; I know my family did.

Für "schnell schnell" habe ich das auch noch nie gehört. Nur im Shakira-Kontext. Wird das denn mit deutschem "W" ausgesprochen oder mit englischem wie bei Shakira?

Wacker in der Bedeutung von „schnell“ oder „eben“ kenne ich aus dem Bereich Ruhrgebiet und Sauerland. „komm mal wacker her!“ ist war in den 80ern in der Gegend nicht unüblich

so etwas gibt es überhaupt gar nicht in Mitteldeutschland. Nie gehört davon.

hab es nur selten gehört aber kann sein, dass es aus dem schwäbischen kommt von "wackeln" mit einem mix aus altem dialekt und babysprache? Kleinkinder wackeln ja gerne mal her wenn sie gehen/laufen und habe oft gehört "Wackel mal her". Ein wilder guess wäre dass es von "Wacker" kommt (im sinne von mutig sein > ein wackerer soldat) und das über die typischen, seltsamen umwege zu dem wurde, vielleicht weil laufen für ein kleinkind gruselig sein kann oder etwas der art.
